# Fedora 20: irqbalance problems in logs, strange behavior

Tags: ssh, fedora

I'm seeing unexplained network behavior, such as sporadic inability to reach
beyond the subnet, passwords rejected for no apparent reason, 
and SSH attempts constantly yielding that irksome man-in-the-middle attack
warning necessitating accepting new keys often (deleting entries in 
the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file to start over again when trying to reach this 
problematic Fedora 20 workstation).
But at other times, everything's fine.

I find no evidence of network intrusion or really anything else wrong with the 
OS, except this...

```
Nov 13 22:29:17 hostname /usr/sbin/irqbalance: irq 118 affinity_hint subset empty
```

The above message appears literally every 10 seconds or less in 
the `/var/log/messages` file. No idea what it is or means. Can this be at the
heart of what's troubling this installation?

Answer (score 0):

The logged messages generally shouldn't cause your problem. It's irqbalance complaining and Net Wisdom say to disable affinity hints:

*irqbalance ... --hintpolicy=ignore*

(usually in startup script OPTIONS or in the default config) which may or may not be a good direction since it disables some advanced features of irqbalance; it definitely going to make the logged message disappear.

Your problems will not go away with high probability, though.

[**update**] but maybe it can help according to [this redhat bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=837049).